# Is it possible to recursively apply `core::convert::Into::Into()`?

Tags: rust

Consider:

```rust
struct A;
struct B;
struct C;
struct D;

impl Into<D> for C { /* ... */ }
impl Into<C> for B { /* ... */ }
impl Into<B> for A { /* ... */ }
```

In this case, to get D, from A, I can:

```rust
// example 1
let I = A;
let II: B = I.into();
let III: C = II.into();
let IV: D = III.into();
```

I am not allowed to:

```rust
// example 2
let I = A;
let II: D = I.into()
```

Because A is not *directly* convertible to D, but neither can I:

```rust
// example 3
let I = A;
let II: D = I.into().into().into();
```

Because rust has a hard time inferring the intermediate types.

Is there some way I can recursively get from `A` to `D` without having to hold the compiler's hand at each step of the process like in example 1?

Comment: You can explicitly defined `impl Into<D> for A { /* ... */ }` and such. Is that something you're trying to avoid?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but generally you'd implement `From` and not `Into` because you'd get that automatically due to its blanket implementation.

Comment: i’d like to implicitly implement these, if possible. I use `into` and not `from` just because it’s a bit more intuitive as an example

Comment: You can't get that implicitly, so you'd have to define the conversion yourself. "it’s a bit more intuitive as an example" Using `.into()` is perfect, my point is that if you implement `impl From<A> for D {`, you can also use `.into()`. See https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html "One should avoid implementing `Into` and implement `From` instead."

Comment: Right, but my `impl From<A> for D` is going to need a ton of compiler handholding, since it's going to look like example 1. That syntax kinda sucks

Comment: No disagreement there, but at least then it's centralized into one place. Hopefully eventually something `let IV: D = ((I.into(): B).into(): C).into();` will work to avoid all the separate assignments. You can however easily do `let IV: D = D::from(C::from(B::from(I)));` right now.

Comment: Oh that last syntax is good. I was trying to work out if there was syntax for that